# Free antivirus without firewall

Tags: gratis, windows-7, antivirus

What antivirus would you recommend for me to use on my personal computer at home?

I used to run Linux, but nowadays, I have to use Windows 7 because of changes at work, therefore, I don't know what antivirus to use.

I don't want the antivirus to have a firewall included. I hate it.
And, no silent mode anymore, please.

Comment: It looks like you did not search: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+antivirus

Comment: Or of [Gratis antivirus for Windows 7 x64 requiring little attention](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/12019/185) / [Gratis antivirus software (accessible by screen readers) without pop-up ads](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4463/185)