# Podcast downloader for Windows 7, running in the background

Tags: gratis, windows-7, download-manager, rss, podcast

I’m looking for a podcast downloader for Windows 7 (must be gratis, should be FLOSS).

It’s important that it works automatically, in the background. It’s for a blind user that checks a specific folder for new episodes, opens them with her favorite media player, and deletes them manually after.

Required features:

- autostart with Windows, without opening a window in the taskbar (just an icon in the notification area)
- support the common feed formats (Atom, various RSS)
- specify a folder in which the tool automatically creates a folder per podcast feed
- automatically check for new episodes and download them
- deleting/moving episodes from the folder should never result in a re-download

Desired features:

- configurable size limit (either globally or per feed) after which it doesn’t download new files anymore; just to make sure that it doesn’t fill up the hard disk if a feed goes crazy
- when adding a feed, only download the last episode, not all of them

We used [Juice](http://juicereceiver.sourceforge.net/) before, which worked great (especially that everything happens in the background), but now development seems to have stopped, Windows 7 is not supported (it works somewhat in compatibility mode, but not great), it is downloading even very old episodes of feeds although configured differently (and I can’t seem to stop the downloads without selecting the episodes one at a time; it currently wants to download more than 1500 files), and it seems to re-download episodes if they get deleted in the folder (although it didn’t do this some time ago).

Comment: Because this is for a blind user, do you want to replace one of the tags with [tag:accessibility]?  There's no right or wrong... just wanted to point out the relevance of that tag to your useful question.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: Thanks! I thought about it, but I think the [tag:accessibility] tag might be more appropriate for questions looking for actual accessibility software (or for something that improves the accessibility), and not just for any software that happens to be used by someone who might *also* need accessibility software, or that needs to be compatible to some accessibility tool ([example](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4463/60)). So essentially the difference between *accessibility* and *accessible*.